# The column 'JUN-2015' was specified multiple times for 'P'

Tags: sql-server

I have created a dynamic pivot and my table has two same dates with diff values ..
i m facing an error when try the pivot

```
Error : the column 'JUN-2015' was specified multiple times for 'P'
```

...........................................................

```
CREATE TABLE #REVENUE
(
ID             INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MONTH]        VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
SALES          DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #REVENUE
([MONTH],SALES)
VALUES
('JAN-2015', 200000.16),
('FEB-2015', 220000.17),
('MAR-2015', 227000.55),
('APR-2015', 247032.75),
('MAY-2015', 287652.75),
('JUN-2015', 265756.75),
('JUN-2015', 265756.75)



DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
 @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME([MONTH]) 
                    FROM #REVENUE
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


SELECT @query = 
'SELECT * FROM
(SELECT     
    [MONTH], 
    SALES
FROM #REVENUE)X
PIVOT 
(
    AVG(SALES)
    for [MONTH] in (' + @cols + ')
) P'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. Your table `#REVENUE` has the value `'JUN-2015'` in it multiple times, let you're converting all of them to columns. Try `DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([MONTH])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select `@cols` you'll see the issue

[image]

Please use `DISTINCT` to avoid the situation:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([MONTH]) 
                    FROM #REVENUE
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```